# how to handle mouse clicks for modified page content in firefox extension using addon sdk

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon-sdk

I've written a code to modify a content of a specific webpage (http://www.example.com) and show a box with some texts and images. as shown here:

**main.js**

```
"use strict";

var self = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

var allimageurls=[]
allimageurls.push({
                    logo:self.data.url("logo.png"),
                    panel:self.data.url("panel.png"),
                    panel_css_url:self.data.url("__some_css.css")
                });

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "http://www.example.com/",
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-1.11.1.min.js"),
                        self.data.url("panel.js")],
    attachTo: 'top',
    contentScriptWhen:'end',
    onAttach: function(worker) {
                                worker.port.emit("urls",allimageurls);
                               }

});
```

and **panel.js**

```
var img1;
var img2;

self.port.on("urls",function(allimageurls){
    img1=allimageurls[0].logo;
    img2=allimageurls[0].panel;
    css_url=allimageurls[0].panel_css_url;

    $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+css_url+"' type='text/css'>");
    $("body").append('<div id = "__some_id" class="__some_css_class"><p class="__css_stuff">...</p>     <div id="__important_id" class="__css_again"> <img src="' + img2 + '" /></div></div>');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#__important_id").click(function(){
        alert("function called!");
});
});
```

I've managed to show the thing i want to show but click function is not working(it's supposed to alert when some one clicked on the img2)

what is it i'm doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're telling the script to be attached after the page finished loading (`contentScriptWhen:'end'`), the jquery document ready event will never fire. Panel.js should look like:

and **panel.js**

```
var img1;
var img2;

self.port.on("urls",function(allimageurls){
    img1=allimageurls[0].logo;
    img2=allimageurls[0].panel;
    css_url=allimageurls[0].panel_css_url;

    $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+css_url+"' type='text/css'>");
    $("body").append('<div id = "__some_id" class="__some_css_class"><p class="__css_stuff">...</p>     <div id="__important_id" class="__css_again"> <img src="' + img2 + '" /></div></div>');
});

$("#__important_id").click(function(){
    alert("function called!");
});
```

---

As an aside, you can apply a css file in the `pageMod` constructor using the `contentStyleFile` property, and you can pass an object to the content script using `contentScriptOptions`. That object is then accessible in the content script as `self.options`. Your new code would look like this.
**main.js**

```
"use strict";

var self = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var allimageurls=[];

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://www.example.com/",
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-1.11.1.min.js"),
            self.data.url("panel.js")],
  attachTo: 'top',
  contentScriptWhen:'end',
  contentScriptOptions: {
    logo:self.data.url("logo.png"),
    panel:self.data.url("panel.png"),
  },
  contentStyleFile: self.data.url("__some_css.css"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.emit("urls",allimageurls);
  }             
});
```

and **panel.js**

```
var img1 = self.options.logo;
var img2 = self.options.panel;

$("body").append('<div id = "__some_id" class="__some_css_class"><p class="__css_stuff">...</p>     <div id="__important_id" class="__css_again"> <img src="' + img2 + '" /></div></div>');

$("#__important_id").click(function(){
    alert("function called!");
});

self.port.on("urls",function(allimageurls) {
  // Do something with the image URLs
});
```

Comment: actually at first click was not wrapped in document.ready, after reading some answers to similar questions i thought it should be wrapped like that,anyway, let me check your answer :)

Comment: the new main.js and panel.js worked just fine, thanks.